# Assign array of values to text field using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to assign values in array to a text-field using Rails 3.I have a table which is given below.

> paymenttable.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
                <th class="text-center">Date</th>
                <th class="text-center">Receipt No.</th>
                <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @result.each do |r| %>
            <tr>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :r_value,params[:r_value]=r %>
                <th class="text-center"><%= check_box_tag :check_value, 1, :id => "checkbox1-1"  %></th>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.id %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.c_date %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%= r.Receipt_No %></td>
                <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i><%= r.v_amount %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

> payment_controller.rb:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

    def payment
        @payment=Vendor.new
        @add_payment=AddPayment.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
            format.js
        end

    end
    def check_type  
        if params[:commit]=="submit"
            @vendor_type = PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).map{|v|[v.v_catagory ,v.Receipt_No]}
            #@vendor_type = PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).pluck(:v_catagory)
            @output=[]
            #@result=[]
            @r_no=[]
            @vendor_type.each do |i|
              if i.first == params[:payment][:s_catagory]
                @output << i[1]
              end  
            end  
            @output.each do |o|
                @r_no << o
                @result = PaymentVendor.where(:Receipt_No => @r_no,:v_catagory =>  params[:payment][:s_catagory],:v_name => params[:v_name] )
            end
               #puts "#{val} => #{index}" 
               #puts output1[index]
               #@result = PaymentVendor.where(:Receipt_No =>  @output[index],:v_catagory =>  params[:payment][:s_catagory],:v_name => params[:v_name] )

        else
            @v_name=Vendor.where(:s_catagory => params[:payment][:s_catagory] ).pluck(:v_name)
        end
    end
    def add_payment
        if params[:commit]
            params[:check_value] == '1' ? remember : forget
            #if params[:add_payment][:p_catagory]=="Cash"
                #@abc=true
                #@add_payment=AddPayment.create(:p_catagory => params[:add_payment][:p_catagory],:paid_amount => params[:check_value][:value].v_amount,:total_claim => 1 )

            #else
                #@abc=true
                #@add_payment=AddPayment.create(:p_catagory => params[:add_payment][:p_catagory],:paid_amount => params[:value].v_amount,:total_claim => 1,:chk_details => params[:chk_details],:chk_no => params[:chk_no]  )
            #end
        else
            if params[:add_payment][:p_catagory]=="Cheque"
                @chk=true
            end
        end
    end
    private
    def remember
        @r_value=[]
        @r_value << params[:r_value]
        @r_value.each do |value|
            #@add_payment=AddPayment.create(:p_catagory => params[:add_payment][:p_catagory],:paid_amount => value.v_amount,:total_claim => 1,:chk_details => params[:chk_details],:chk_no => params[:chk_no]  )
            @abc=true
        end
    end

end
```

I have assigned like the above way which is given in the table.But when i checked in generated html ,this hidden field gave the output as `<input id="r_value" name="r_value" type="hidden" value="#<PaymentVendor:0x2c0fd90>">`.No value i found here.Actually i need `r.v_amount` in each repetition of loop and store all v_amount value in that hidden field in array.Please help me.

Comment: In your `check_type` method you are assigning instance variable `@result` in loop which will be override on each loop. It doesn't make any sense. Instead assign all the value as  Array.

Comment: @ Gagan : Ok,I solved this probelm.Can you help me for how can i access checked property in rails if i generated output is like this <input checked="checked" id="deatils_" name="deatils[]" type="checkbox" value="60.0">.

Comment: Which parameter you are passing for checkbox?

Comment: @Gagan : i have rails checkbox like this <%= check_box_tag "deatils[]" ,{:checked => true} ,:id =>"abc" %>.from the begining it is checked.I need how i can chcek wether it is checked or not in controller action.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just show your msg. change it to `<%= check_box_tag "deatils[]",true ,:id =>"abc" %>` and in your controller check it like `if params[:deatils]` if check box is checked then it entered to `true` part otherwise in `else` part

Comment: @ Gagan : if i am assigning some value to details[],then how it will check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76635/discussion-between-satya-and-gagan-gami).

Comment: then assign like this `<%= check_box_tag "deatils[]", 60 , true, :id =>"abc" %>` and in your controller true part of if condition as mentioned in my last comment.. you can access value like `params[:deatils][0].to_i` you will get "60" so to convert into integer use `to_i` method as i did